# How to pass connection from nginx to another server (reverse proxy?)

Tags: proxy, ssl, nginx

I have an [Openfire](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) daemon running at `http://192.168.2.33:9090` (no SSL) and I want to bind it via proxy to the host name `https://openfire.example.com` (I have SSL certificate for it).

How would I do this? When I add SSL string to nginx config it shows an SSL error. Here is my current config without ssl support:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name openfire.example.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.2.33:9090;
            proxy_redirect http://192.168.2.33:9090/ $scheme://$host/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_read_timeout 20d;
            auth_basic "Private Property";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        }
}
```

This configuration produces an Error 502 Bad gateway.

A minor change (as seen below) leads to ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    listen *:443;
    server_name openfire.example.com;

    ssl                     on;
        ssl_protocols           SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/openfire.example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/openfire.example.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ https://openfire.example.com$1 permanent;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.2.33:9090;
        proxy_redirect http://192.168.2.33:9090/ $scheme://$host/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout 20d;
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of error is being shown?

Comment: @Seth
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Config for that error: https://pastebin.com/crYLnx8N

Comment: Why does that configuration include a redirect? What's the idea behind the redirect? Your [`proxy_read_timeout`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout) seems a bit excessive. As for Error 502, did you check the logs of the Openfire server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should have an SSL certificate set in web-console at your openfire server.
2. This certificate should be set in following nginx conf:

   ```
   server {
       listen *:80;
       server_name openfire.example.com;
       proxy_set_header Host openfire.example.com;
       location / {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ https://openfire.example.com$1 permanent;
       }
   }

   server {
       listen *:443;
       server_name openfire.example.com;
       proxy_set_header Host openfire.example.com;

       #The port used for secured Admin Console access:
       set $openfire_port 9091;
       #IP address for machine running openfire server:
       set $openfire_ip 192.168.2.33;
       ssl     on;
       ssl_protocols     SSLv3 TLSv1;
       ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/openfire.example.com/fullchain.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/openfire.example.com/privkey.pem;

   location / {
       proxy_pass https://$openfire_ip:$openfire_port;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add comment, so adding this as an answer. I was looking for similar thing, I was trying to pass traffic coming into my raspberry pi 4 to another pi (pi zero w). I followed the answer above, with some updates and I though to share with others (just for a reference for other users who might have come across to this answer after many years).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name openfire.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name openfire.example.com;
    # We need to pass the request to server so that
    # if it is hosting multiple sites hosted, it knows which one to serve
    proxy_set_header Host openfire.example.com;

    ssl     on;
    # tlsv1 is not supported by most of the browsers
    ssl_protocols     SSLv3 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/openfire.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/openfire.example.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://192.168.2.33:9091;
    }
}
```

as the `$openfire_ip` and `$openfire_port` was not used more than once, I think it's not needed to set it up as a variable.